# PHP json_encode umlauts

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm getting json strings from an HTTP API. The content type is Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8.

I then proceed to write the strings to a file using.

```
fwrite($fp, json_encode($post));
```

The strings contain encodings for umlauts as follows.

> Au\u00dfenministerium verh\u00e4ngte Reisewarnung f\u00fcr Kroatien in
> Kraft getreten.

This should be.

> Außenministerium verhängte Reisewarnung für Kroatien in Kraft
> getreten.

**How can I encode the strings to write umlauts to files and not their encoding?**

I tried the following.

```
<?php
$string = "Au\u00dfenministerium verh\u00e4ngte Reisewarnung f\u00fcr Kroatien in Kraft getreten.";
$string = utf8_encode($string);
echo $string;
```

The output of this script still shows the encoding.

Comment: Do you have the html tag `<meta charset="utf-8">` on the page?

Comment: I'm not using html. My code is a php script. The full code is here https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/php_utf8/blob/master/get_documents_so.php .

Comment: Stop using `utf8_encode()`, it's a terribly-named function that doesn't do what you think it does. It's a forced conversion that doesn't detect or care about the input encoding and will corrupt your data more often than not. Same goes for `utf8_decode()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the default behaviour of the `json_encode` function, but you can override this by specifying the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option. So for example:

```
json_encode("Außenministerium", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

And in your code you should do:

```
fwrite($fp, json_encode($post, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Also check out which other options you can use in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)